# jquery to typescriptconversion giving error

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

Getting error while converting below jquery code to type script

```
$("#reqDate-ev").val(this.selection.requestDt);
```

[image]

If I split it into two lines its working without any error

```
var b:any = document.getElementById("reqDate-ev");
b.value = this.selection.requestDt;
```

Whats the issue in doing it in single line?

Comment: Remove `:any` from your second example and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no element with `id="reqDate-ev"`, the value of `document.getElementById("reqDate-ev")` is going to be `null`. That is what it warns you in the first code.

Whereas, in the second code snippet, you typecast the value to `any` type, so Typescript does not care about the content inside the variable `b`.

It's always better to do have an existence check on the element before accessing its value.

In JQuery, `$("#reqDate-ev")` returns an object instance and not the actual DOM element. So, when you call `val()` function on the instance, the library internally checks for the existence of the element.